# How to turn off array range check

Tags: arrays, go, range

I would like to write an effective implementation of linear searching algorithm in Go. The key feature of this algorithm is removing array range check from main loop. My source code is:

```
func Contains(a []int, x int) bool {
    var t, i = a[0], len(a) - 1
    a[0] = x
    for a[i] != x {
        i--
    }
    a[0] = t
    return a[i] == x
}
```

But the Go compiler (go version go1.12.11 linux/386) inserts array range checking assembler instructions into the produced executable:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main.Contains:
   0x080c1ed0 <+0>: mov    ecx,DWORD PTR gs:0x0
   0x080c1ed7 <+7>: mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x080c1edd <+13>:    cmp    esp,DWORD PTR [ecx+0x8]
   0x080c1ee0 <+16>:    jbe    0x80c1f24 <main.Contains+84>
   0x080c1ee2 <+18>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x8]
   0x080c1ee6 <+22>:    test   eax,eax
   0x080c1ee8 <+24>:    jbe    0x80c1f1d <main.Contains+77>
   0x080c1eea <+26>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x4]
   0x080c1eee <+30>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ecx]
   0x080c1ef0 <+32>:    mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x10]
   0x080c1ef4 <+36>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ecx],ebx
   0x080c1ef6 <+38>:    lea    ebp,[eax-0x1]
   0x080c1ef9 <+41>:    jmp    0x80c1efc <main.Contains+44>
## BEGIN OF MAIN LOOP
   0x080c1efb <+43>:    dec    ebp
!!!! UNNECESSARY ARRAY RANGE CHECK
!! 0x080c1efc <+44>:    cmp    ebp,eax
!! 0x080c1efe <+46>:    jae    0x80c1f16 <main.Contains+70>
!!!!
   0x080c1f00 <+48>:    mov    esi,DWORD PTR [ecx+ebp*4]
   0x080c1f03 <+51>:    cmp    esi,ebx
   0x080c1f05 <+53>:    jne    0x80c1efb <main.Contains+43>
## END OF MAIN LOOP
   0x080c1f07 <+55>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ecx],edx
   0x080c1f09 <+57>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ecx+ebp*4]
   0x080c1f0c <+60>:    cmp    eax,ebx
   0x080c1f0e <+62>:    sete   al
   0x080c1f11 <+65>:    mov    BYTE PTR [esp+0x14],al
   0x080c1f15 <+69>:    ret    
   0x080c1f16 <+70>:    call   0x806b270 <runtime.panicindex>
   0x080c1f1b <+75>:    ud2    
   0x080c1f1d <+77>:    call   0x806b270 <runtime.panicindex>
   0x080c1f22 <+82>:    ud2    
   0x080c1f24 <+84>:    call   0x808fc30 <runtime.morestack_noctxt>
   0x080c1f29 <+89>:    jmp    0x80c1ed0 <main.Contains>
End of assembler dump.
```

How do I get binary I expected, without array range checking? Is there an option of the Go compiler to turn this checking off? Is there a way to rewrite the source code for getting expected binary?

Comment: What's the assembly output if you use an array instead of a slice?

Comment: Removing array range check would make your code unreliable,   Array bound check is removed by the compiler when it can ensure that a boundary overflow can't occur. Your function is very far from that.

Comment: @chmike Do you mean that upper bound overflow checking after index decrement makes this code more safe?

Comment: Run `go tool compile -h` and look for -B. But honestly: You really do not want this!!

Comment: I'm not expert in assembly code. And I don't know for sure. It looks like a test against overflow which make sense because it's just before the x[i]. What I don't see is the test to detect underflow.

Comment: @CanobbioE Replaced function header with "func Contains2 (a *[max]int, x int) bool". Initial range check disappeared (before the loop), but internal range check remained in the same place.

Comment: @chmike The goal of this implementation of linear search algorithm is to replace array bounds check with check for barrier element. In low level languages this reduces by half number of comparisons in the main loop and improves performance.

Comment: @Volker You answered my question, thank you very much. The command you recommend does exactly what I expected.

Comment: "In low level languages this reduces by half number of comparisons in the main loop and improves performance." Go is not a low-level language though. Do not try to optimize it as if it were C.

Comment: @Adrian This algorithm gives up to 20% better performance than "generic" linear search. It is quite simple. I understand how it works. Why not to use it?

Comment: Because you're giving up a major safety aspect of Go. If the safety features of Go are a significant enough performance impact to disable them, you shouldn't be using Go, you should be using something like C that doesn't have them in the first place.

Comment: @Adrian Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Write code in the Go Programming Language:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

For idiomatic code, Go optimizing compilers often eliminate unnecessary bounds checks.

---

For example,

```
func Contains(a []int, x int) bool {
    for _, y := range a {
        if y == x {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

---

```
$ go version
go version devel +71239b4f49 Mon Jan 20 15:06:42 2020 +0000 linux/amd64
$

00000000004583b0 <main.Contains>:
package main

func Contains(a []int, x int) bool {
    for _, y := range a {
  4583b0:   48 8b 44 24 10          mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
  4583b5:   48 8b 4c 24 20          mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20]
  4583ba:   48 8b 54 24 08          mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
  4583bf:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
  4583c1:   eb 03                   jmp    4583c6 <main.Contains+0x16>
  4583c3:   48 ff c3                inc    rbx
  4583c6:   48 39 c3                cmp    rbx,rax
  4583c9:   7d 0f                   jge    4583da <main.Contains+0x2a>
  4583cb:   48 8b 34 da             mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rdx+rbx*8]
        if y == x {
  4583cf:   48 39 ce                cmp    rsi,rcx
  4583d2:   75 ef                   jne    4583c3 <main.Contains+0x13>
            return true
  4583d4:   c6 44 24 28 01          mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x28],0x1
  4583d9:   c3                      ret    
        }
    }
    return false
  4583da:   c6 44 24 28 00          mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x28],0x0
  4583df:   c3                      ret    

00000000004583e0 <main.main>:
}
```

---

```
$ go version
go version go1.12.15 linux/386
$

0808e9a0 <main.Contains>:
package main

func Contains(a []int, x int) bool {
 808e9a0:   65 8b 0d 00 00 00 00    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR gs:0x0
 808e9a7:   8b 89 fc ff ff ff       mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
 808e9ad:   3b 61 08                cmp    esp,DWORD PTR [ecx+0x8]
 808e9b0:   76 28                   jbe    808e9da <main.Contains+0x3a>
    for _, y := range a {
 808e9b2:   8b 44 24 08             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x8]
 808e9b6:   8b 4c 24 10             mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x10]
 808e9ba:   8b 54 24 04             mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x4]
 808e9be:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
 808e9c0:   eb 01                   jmp    808e9c3 <main.Contains+0x23>
 808e9c2:   43                      inc    ebx
 808e9c3:   39 c3                   cmp    ebx,eax
 808e9c5:   7d 0d                   jge    808e9d4 <main.Contains+0x34>
 808e9c7:   8b 2c 9a                mov    ebp,DWORD PTR [edx+ebx*4]
        if y == x {
 808e9ca:   39 cd                   cmp    ebp,ecx
 808e9cc:   75 f4                   jne    808e9c2 <main.Contains+0x22>
            return true
 808e9ce:   c6 44 24 14 01          mov    BYTE PTR [esp+0x14],0x1
 808e9d3:   c3                      ret    
        }
    }
    return false
 808e9d4:   c6 44 24 14 00          mov    BYTE PTR [esp+0x14],0x0
 808e9d9:   c3                      ret    
func Contains(a []int, x int) bool {
 808e9da:   e8 21 af ff ff          call   8089900 <runtime.morestack_noctxt>
 808e9df:   eb bf                   jmp    808e9a0 <main.Contains>
 808e9e1:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e2:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e3:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e4:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e5:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e6:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e7:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e8:   cc                      int3   
 808e9e9:   cc                      int3   
 808e9ea:   cc                      int3   
 808e9eb:   cc                      int3   
 808e9ec:   cc                      int3   
 808e9ed:   cc                      int3   
 808e9ee:   cc                      int3   
 808e9ef:   cc                      int3   

0808e9f0 <main.main>:
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But produced code contains array bounds check: cmp    ebx,eax; jge    808e9d4 <main.Contains+0x34> -- from the language statement for ... range. This is not what I expected.

Comment: @R0bur: The compiler is not going to use a sentinel because it is not safe to corrupt the array, even temporarily . Therefore, it checks to see if it has reached the end of the array. And, it takes about the same CPU time in a benchmark: 1215 ns/op compiler versus 1219 ns/op you . Meaningless microbenchmarks produce meaningless results.

Comment: My benchmark gives up to 20% performance (for the worst case - "not found") for the optimized implementation of linear search algorithm with compiling option -B as @Volker prompted.

Comment: @R0bur: Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the length of the slice is zero initially, the code will use an out-of-bounds array index right off the bat.  So it's probably good that the Go compiler put in a bounds check.

Even if the length is nonzero, if the slice is shared with another user, the sentinel value you put in `a[0]` could be replaced by some other value.  The loop would then run off the beginning of the array, if the value is not found.

(If the underlying array isn't shared, and the length is at least 1, the code is valid, but I think you're expecting a bit much of the compiler if you want it to make the "unshared" assumption.)

Answer (score 0):

Check in your code is not a range check but slice bounds check.

There's only one way to avoid this check is to use unsafe tricks:

```golang
func Contains(a []int, x int) bool {
    /*
          take a pointer of content, contained in slice header
    */
    p := *(*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    offset := uintptr(0)

    //l := uintptr(len(a)) * unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))
loop:

    /*
          optional range check
    */  
    //if offset == l {
    //  goto ret_false
    //}


    /*
          a[i] == x, but without bounds check
    */
    if *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(p) + offset)) == x {
        return true
    }

    /*
          i++
    */
    offset += unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))

    goto loop

//ret_false:

    return false
}
```

You can also use **arrays**, but it requires to be handwritten:

```golang
func Contains(a [3]int, x int) bool {
    _ = a[2] // do boundary check once

    // no boundary checks for this line:
    if a[0] == x {
        return true
    }

    // no boundary checks for this line:
    if a[1] == x {
        return true
    }

    // no boundary checks for this line:
    if a[2] == x {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```